# How to target similar classes and their children with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I use AE Templates in Wordpress to create templates which are used around the website, so I don't have to change every occurrence of a single template every time I need to update some information. In my case I have tens of these templates which are exactly the same apart from some text and an image, so they all have exactly the same CSS except for some unique identifiers in classes.

Here's an example:

```
.elementor-3464 .elementor-element.elementor-element-380443b9 > .elementor-element-populated{
    some-rules;
}
```

This is a line of CSS which is the same for all templates, except `3464` and `380443b9` change from template to template.

It seems a waste of code to me to load all CSS files for every web page with multiple templates with the same CSS. Is there a way I can target all templates by rewriting the above line to be arbitrary for any ID number/sequence (`3464` and `380443b9`)?

I was hoping I could use the [class*=...] selector but it doesn't work.
I tried this as a replacement for the above example:

```
[class^="elementor-"] [class*="elementor-element-"] > .elementor-element-populated{
   some-rules;
}
```

Comment: Use `selector .css-selector` in the Custom CSS section to make your work easier.

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/kpuvotwj/

Comment: @Kaiido why doesn't it work on both "hello" elements? Shouldn't the rule with [class*=] overwrite the first one?

Comment: @R2vale because the first rule as a double class selector while the corresponding attribute is alone: `.elementor-element.elementor-element-380443b9` vs `[class*="elementor-element-"]`. This makes the first one has a *slightly* higher specificity than the other. If you had e.g  `[class*="element"][class*="elementor-element-"]` then they would have the same specifity and order would rule (both would be green).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[class^="elementor-"]` will only work if the class list begins with "elementor-". If there is another class before it, e.g. `class="elementor elementor-1234"` then it will not work.

You might need to use:

```
[class*="elementor-"] [class*="elementor-element-"] > .elementor-element-populated{
   some-rules;
}
```